# Хочу (—) и буду/делаю

Tags: пунктуация, тире, и

Нужно ли ставить тире?

*Хочу (—) и буду.*

*Хочу (—) и делаю.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта **возможны:**

(1) Мораль **психологов:** *Хочу **и бУду**. Хочу **и дЕлаю***.

В чем мораль? Если/когда хочешь, то делай.

Мораль **другая, человек ["неограниченный"](https://lexcodex.ru/ask/samoneogranicennyi-celovek-kak-nazyvayut-togo-kto-delaet-cto-xocet):** Что **хочу,** то и **делаю**. Не надо мне указывать.

(2) *ХочУ — **и бУду**. **ХочУ — и дЕлаю**.*

Тире  в тех же случаях, только произношение **с паузой**. Часть фразы как бы пропущена, но понять можно **по тексту**.

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

**Вариант 1.**

**[Хочу и буду](https://dzen.ru/a/Y8_dyOmsOTVFQ0_b)**

**Хочу, могу и делаю**: Психолог назвала три слова для внутренней мотивации.

**Вариант 2.**

Ни больше, ни меньше. Я **хочу и делаю.** Хочу спать — сплю.

— Да нет же, нет! **Хочу и буду!** По-разному могут складываться обстоятельства, но я — рядом с тобой...

**«Хочу и делаю...»** – Ты говорил с беспечностью И отворачивался к злому от добра.

Comment: В общем, в разговорном тире может не стоять? По справочнику Розенталя, сочетание _ни больше ни меньше_ не разделяется запятой, кстати.

Comment: Здесь дело не в стиле.  Две морали нужно различать. Но сказаны они могут быть по-разному: спокойно или с экспрессией.  Эти эмоции и отражают знаки.  // Ни бОльше, ни мЕньше – авторский выбор.

Comment: При разговоре-то, если паузы нет, тире можно не ставить?

Comment: Ситуация чаще именно разговорная. Паузой  вы логически выделяете ХОЧУ, подчеркиваете значимость желания, веру в то, что всего можно добиться при желании. Или же уверенность в том, что можно делать все что хочешь, это как бы право свободного человека.  Семантика по контексту.  И эмоциональность тоже по ситуации.